# Importing IP address ranges to DB table - how to check for range conflicts in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ip-address

I have a table in a SQL Server database that stores the start and end NUMERIC IP address values (not IPv4).  I will be importing additional IP address ranges into this table.  Prior to the actual import, does anyone know how to check, using T-SQL if any of the ranges to be imported conflict with any existing ranges?  Thank you.

Comment: What does your table schema look like? Are you using two columns to represent the top and bottom of the range?

Comment: Do you mean start *and* end?

Comment: Yes, two columns, one for start AND one for end.

Comment: You should really show sample data and what you want to do.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "NUMERIC IP address values".  Is this a multi-part naming convention?  IPv6?

Comment: http://www.smartconversion.com/unit_conversion/IP_Address_Converter.aspx    so something like 209.142.176.5 is stored as the numeric equiv, 3515789317

Answer (score 1):

Given a table something like

```
 create table IPRanges (
      IPStart int not null unique nonclustered
     ,IPEnd   int not null unique nonclustered
     --other fields
  )
```

then the function here will perform the required test. If desired a `TOP 1` could be added to the select.

```
create function dbo.ConflictingRanges(@IPStart int, @IPEnd int)
returns table return(
    select IPStart, IPEnd
    from dbo.IPRanges
    where IPStart <= @IPEnd
      and IPEnd   >= @IPStart
)
```

The following test case

```
insert dbo.IPRanges(IPStart,IPEnd)
values (2,4)
      ,(8,10)
      ,(15,20)
;

with trials as (
    select * from (values
         ( 0, 1)
        ,( 3, 5)
        ,( 9, 9)
        ,(19,21)
        ,(25,30)
        ,( 1,35)
    )trials(IPStart,IPEnd)
)
select 
     trials.IPStart
    ,trials.IPEnd
    ,data.IPStart as conflictStart
    ,data.IPEnd   as ConflictEnd
from trials
outer apply dbo.ConflictingRanges(trials.IPStart,trials.IPEnd) data;
```

yields:

```
IPStart     IPEnd       conflictStart ConflictEnd
----------- ----------- ------------- -----------
0           1           NULL          NULL
3           5           2             4
9           9           8             10
19          21          15            20
25          30          NULL          NULL
1           35          2             4
1           35          8             10
1           35          15            20
```

which could be converted to a Boolean result by returning `count(*)` instead of the actual conflicting values if desired.

Answer (score 1):

The below process shows how to convert IP Addresses. Once you have the IP's transplanted to numbers, checking existing ranges would be easy from there. If you need further clarification please refer [Here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-to-convert-ip-addresses-between-bigi/)

```
DECLARE @StrIPOctet VARCHAR(15) = '192.168.10.255'
DECLARE @StrIPlong FLOAT = '3232238081'
DECLARE @Octet1 BIGINT
DECLARE @Octet2 TINYINT
DECLARE @Octet3 TINYINT
DECLARE @Octet4 TINYINT
DECLARE @OctetPart BIGINT

SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@StrIPOctet, 1)) 
    + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@StrIPOctet, 2)) * 256 
    + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@StrIPOctet, 3)) * 65536 
    + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@StrIPOctet, 4)) * 16777216

SET @Octet1 = @StrIPlong / 16777216
SET @OctetPart = @StrIPlong - @Octet1 * 16777216
SET @Octet2 = @OctetPart / 65536
SET @OctetPart = @OctetPart - @Octet2 * 65536
SET @Octet3 = @OctetPart / 256
SET @Octet4 = @OctetPart - @Octet3 * 256

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Octet1) + '.' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Octet2) + '.' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Octet3) + '.' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Octet4)
```